# Get values from a json with condition and convert it to a list of object

Tags: c#, json

With my code below I am able to get the value of:

```
{
  "101": [
    {
      "name": "Lane 2",
      "code": 21
    },
    {
      "name": "Lane 4",
      "code": 41
    },
    {
      "name": "Lane 6",
      "code": 61
    },
    {
      "name": "Lane 8",
      "code": 81
    },
    {
      "name": "Lane 9",
      "code": 91
    },
    {
      "name": "Lane 11",
      "code": 111
    }
  ],
  "103": [
     {
      "name": "Lane 3",
      "code": 31
    },
    {
      "name": "Lane 6",
      "code": 61
    }
  ],
  "105": [
     {
      "name": "Lane 6",
      "code": 61
    },
    {
      "name": "Lane 9",
      "code": 91
    }
  ],
  "107": [
     {
      "name": "Lane 3",
      "code": 31
    },
    {
      "name": "Lane 5",
      "code": 51
    }
  ],
  "109": [
     {
      "name": "Lane 3",
      "code": 31
    },
    {
      "name": "Lane 5",
      "code": 61
    }
  ],
  "111": [
     {
      "name": "Lane 2",
      "code": 21
    },
    {
      "name": "Lane 4",
      "code": 41
    },
    {
      "name": "Lane 6",
      "code": 61
    }
  ],
  "113": [
     {
      "name": "Lane 4",
      "code": 41
    },
    {
      "name": "Lane 6",
      "code": 61
    },
    {
      "name": "Lane 8",
      "code": 81
    },
    {
      "name": "Lane 9",
      "code": 91
    }
  ],
  "115": [
     {
      "name": "Lane 3",
      "code": 31
    },
    {
      "name": "Lane 5",
      "code": 51
    }
  ],
  "117": [
     {
      "name": "Lane 3",
      "code": 31
    },
    {
      "name": "Lane 4",
      "code": 41
    },
    {
      "name": "Lane 6",
      "code": 61
    }
  ]
}
```

What I need is to be able to select through the json file for a certain value then get its children. Example when I send "101" I should be able to get:

```
    {
      "name": "Lane 2",
      "code": 21
    },
    {
      "name": "Lane 4",
      "code": 41
    },
    {
      "name": "Lane 6",
      "code": 61
    },
    {
      "name": "Lane 8",
      "code": 81
    },
    {
      "name": "Lane 9",
      "code": 91
    },
    {
      "name": "Lane 11",
      "code": 111
    }
```

and place it on a class. This is my code so far:

**Lane.json**

```
{
  "101": [
    {
      "name": "Lane 2",
      "code": 21
    }
    {
      "name": "Lane 4",
      "code": 41
    },
    {
      "name": "Lane 6",
      "code": 61
    },
    {
      "name": "Lane 8",
      "code": 81
    },
    {
      "name": "Lane 9",
      "code": 91
    },
    {
      "name": "Lane 11",
      "code": 111
    }
  ],
  "103": [
     {
      "name": "Lane 3",
      "code": 31
    },
    {
      "name": "Lane 6",
      "code": 61
    }
  ],
  "105": [
     {
      "name": "Lane 6",
      "code": 61
    },
    {
      "name": "Lane 9",
      "code": 91
    }
  ],
  "107": [
     {
      "name": "Lane 3",
      "code": 31
    },
    {
      "name": "Lane 5",
      "code": 51
    }
  ],
  "109": [
     {
      "name": "Lane 3",
      "code": 31
    },
    {
      "name": "Lane 5",
      "code": 61
    }
  ],
  "111": [
     {
      "name": "Lane 2",
      "code": 21
    },
    {
      "name": "Lane 4",
      "code": 41
    },
    {
      "name": "Lane 6",
      "code": 61
    }
  ],
  "113": [
     {
      "name": "Lane 4",
      "code": 41
    },
    {
      "name": "Lane 6",
      "code": 61
    },
    {
      "name": "Lane 8",
      "code": 81
    },
    {
      "name": "Lane 9",
      "code": 91
    }
  ],
  "115": [
     {
      "name": "Lane 3",
      "code": 31
    },
    {
      "name": "Lane 5",
      "code": 51
    }
  ],
  "117": [
     {
      "name": "Lane 3",
      "code": 31
    },
    {
      "name": "Lane 4",
      "code": 41
    },
    {
      "name": "Lane 6",
      "code": 61
    }
  ]
}
```

**Lane.cs**

```
class Lane
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int code { get; set; }
}

class LaneContainer
{
    public List<Lane> Lane { get; set; }
}
```

This is how I get the values

```
private void cbPlaza_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    Plaza selected = (Plaza)cbPlaza.SelectedValue;

    string fileName = "Lane.json";
    string path = System.IO.Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, @"Data\", fileName);
    var json = File.ReadAllText(path);

    LaneContainer laneContainer = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<LaneContainer>(File.ReadAllText(json));
}
```

I get an error like so:

> Additional information: After parsing a value an unexpected character
>   was encountered: {. Path '101[0]', line 7, position 4.

Can you please help me with this. Thank you.

Comment: There's a missing comma at line 6 in Lane.json, this is where your actual error comes from.

Comment: A short example would be great..

Comment: Validate your Json using any tools, Visual studio can do it, online tools like jsonlint, notepad++ with extention.

Comment: And you don't have a `List<Lane>`, That's a `Dictionary<int,List<Lane>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing a comma and your structure is a `Dictionary<string,List<Lane>>`

```
  class Lane
  {
     public string name { get; set; }
     public int code { get; set; }
  }
```

**Example**

To get `101`

```
var json = File.ReadAllText(path);

var lanes = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, List<Lane>>>(json);
var results = lanes["101"];
```

Comment: Thank you Sir. Exact answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can deserialize to `Dictionary<int, Node[]>` like below and get the specific key you want

```
Dictionary<int, Node[]> myDict = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<int, Node[]>>(json);
var data = myDict[100];
```

Where `Node`

```
public class Node
{
    public int Code { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```